# Railguns as a means of propelling people onto a battlefield (or to another ship)

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

Would it be a good idea to use a railgun to propel a person into combat in a low/zero grav environment, à la human cannonballs in a circus? If a person was strapped into some sort of temporary frame, and launched out of a sizable railgun, would they survive the G-force shock unscathed? Could it be used to launch soldiers with jetpacks or other forms of Futurey stuff safely (relatively) into battle?

Comment: The highest G force that a human is recorded to survive for ~1 second is 25 g. For 10 seconds 'untrained humans' can't exceed 20 g, it appears. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-g-force-that-a-human-can-resist How high of g does your railgun reach, and how long is the duration is the launch?

Comment: No... just: no. The only time you need to shoot a human anywhere in a  hurry is get them out of (a worse) danger. This is why you only see **ejection seats** on combat aircraft.

Comment: Also paratroopers (which your units arguably overlap with) often come up in debates as to if they're viable any longer (or were ever viable). See this link for a rather in-depth discussion on that: https://www.americanmilitaryforum.com/forums/threads/are-airborne-forces-obsolete-paratroopers.727/

Comment: for OP - yes(<80g); no; for @NexTerren http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/55368/20315

Comment: this is the most hardcore thing ive heard

Comment: Some formula one driver crashed directly into a concrete bridge support at full speed, and experienced something like 120g for a very short moment. He survived, but suffered lots of broken bones and internal injuries. Just put your dudes in a rocket pod and accelerate them slowly, there is no need for rapid acceleration at all.

Comment: I was probably thinking of Kenny Brack, at over 200g. Obviously not a happy camper following that one.

Comment: Is the railgun just to be amusing?  Why would you use a railgun, whose primary purpose is to generate 1000's of gees, when far simpler methods exist that are designed to actually operate on the range of human gee-limits.

Comment: Regardless of feasibility, you are slowly decelerating your troops over a combat area (using a parachute etc.). Sounds like a turkey shoot for your enemies.

Comment: This is not off topic.  Combat scenarios and deciding how realistic a technology can be is clearly on topic

Comment: You would need a bullet proof aerodynamic shield in front of the soldier to prevent the Kys turkey shoot scenario and the wind problem.

Comment: Along the lines of Nex Terren's comment on viability, if you can collect the necessary large-scale bombardment equipment, energy and an large supply of other stuff (jetpacks, parachutes, etc) and people less than a mile from the enemy (you need to parachute BEHIND them, not to the front of your own lines), why wouldn't you just launch missiles?  Generating the power and massing the size of stuff 1 mile from a hotspot is nontrivial and I can think of dozens of more useful things a commander might do with such a considerable advantage.

Comment: Extended comment - Given that you are less than a mile from the front lines, if you have line-of-sight you could just shoot people from where you are anyway!  Even if you don't have line-of-sight, unless you need to get over a mountain your high-power railgun will mow down anything else in your path so that you do!  There is just no reason at all to start the slow process of lining people up on a jump pad.  Your enemy is probably sniping them as they line up, as they wait on the launch pad, and then again as they slowly descend later.

Comment: If you have a railgun that can hit the battlefield, why send troops when you can attack the enemy with it?

Comment: While you're using your railgun to transport people to the battlefield, I'm using my railgun to blast birdshot into their paths.  Guess who's going to win?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, just put them in a housing for comfort, protection, and aerodynamics, and accelerate them slowly so as to not feel much physical discomfort.

Wait a second...

[image]

A [Maglev train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev) is basically a railgun for safely shooting people around.

---

Ok, now for realsies. Could you safely launch and land a human with a railgun for a mile? [@Tezra is correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/59043/760) that so long as you accelerate and decelerate them over a long enough distance the felt G-Force is manageable no matter the velocity you need.

Unfortunately humans aren't very aerodynamic. @Tezra estimated 126 m/s but [the terminal velocity for a human in free fall in atmosphere is about 53 m/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Examples). This causes problems during launch, the human is now being pressed at 5Gs against an increasingly hard wall of air. Once launched, drag will cause them to rapidly decelerate and potentially not reach the 1 mile.

An aerodynamic shell would help. This would make the human more aerodynamic, increasing velocity and range, and protect them against being buffeted to death by wind.

Because of this deceleration in transit, they'll approach the catching ramp at a lower speed. Lower speed means less length is needed to safely decelerate, so the "catch" platform needs to be much smaller.

But this is *extremely* dangerous. If the calculations are off, if there's a flaw in the shell, if there unaccounted for wind shifts or turbulence, they'll miss the catch platform. Splat. It's much simpler and safer to use a parachute. They're well understood and provide the person with a modicum of control over their landing.

Comment: if there's an ark, then the person will be at a complete stop at the top (granted for a fraction of a second, the shell deploys a parachute (probably more), the capsule loses much of it's forward momentum, the capsule breaks up, the soldier falls, and when at the right height, deploys their own parachute.

Comment: @XenoDwarf - No. If there is an arc, at the peak altitude the vertical velocity will temporarily be zero, but the horizontal velocity will not. For long flight distances the horizontal component must be very high, so your approach won't work.

Comment: I forgot to specify that, the parachutes are there for the horizontal velocity more than the vertical

Comment: 126m/s is 282 mph and quite fast for parachuting. At these speeds you'd likely want automatic deployment of a [drogue chute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drogue_parachute#Parachuting). This would be used to trigger shell separation, deploy the main chute, and pull the human clear of the shell pieces. Exactly when this happens depends on the scenario.

Comment: Should probably through in that if you use something like a glider, you can get much more distance with less speed, and is A LOT safer.

Comment: But also, if you decelerate with a parachute, this decreases the range of the ballistic flight, since it kills your horizontal velocity and you need to open the chute [at least 30m high](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2003/may/15/thisweekssciencequestions2) (higher if you're not suicidal). Since a ballistic tragectory at 45 degrees, 126m/s would reach a maximum altitude of 123m (in a vacuum), this cuts the range pretty significantly, meaning you have yet more to account for in making the rail gun longer.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to launch the person at 126m/s ([math](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-make-a-Trebuchet-that-could-launch-a-person-one-mile-Mathematically-is-it-possible-and-how-As-a-bonus-how-would-you-do-it-if-you-want-the-person-to-be-alive-after-landing-a-question-that-came-out-of-the-design-of-the-Trebuchet-MS-font)). So to not murder them with [G-Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Human_tolerance) (about 5 gs (49 m/s2)), you need to accelerate them over the course of about 2.5 seconds and need a launch/catch pad about 162m long (Distance = accel*time^2, where time = velocity/accel).

NOTE: (This is HYPER-dangerous, and good luck finding a test pilot, let alone riders. Also, the energy of the rail-gun has to be calibrated to the weight of the passengers, or else they die. I have ignored wind resistance, because else they would die from landing in the wrong place)

Comment: 126 m/s is above the terminal velocity of a human in free fall in atmosphere. The person would feel tremendous wind force. They will also rapidly decelerate and possibly not reach the full mile. Putting them in an aerodynamic shell might help.

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume for a moment that the idea is remotely plausible.

You still need a fairly massive installation (a mass driver with a large enough diameter to house a full equipped soldier, an elevating and traversing mechanism and a fairly large power generation system. Transport vehicles will be needed as well, leaving a fairly large footprint on the ground

[image]

[image]

And of course, there will be a platoon or more of soldiers standing around waiting to be shot out of the cannon. Overall, there will be a lucrative target waiting to be "serviced" by artillery, mortars, fast air or even ground troops (a mile is 1600m, a distance which can be covered in a short time on foot). In fact, many machine-guns have effective ranges of over 2000m when mounted on tripods, so your entire device and all the soldiers waiting to be launched will be under attack in a matter of moments.

Now there is a place where this might make more sense, and that is in space, where there is no aerodynamic drag to slow the troops down, and large power plants would be common on spacecraft. A spacecraft might be able to disgorge a large number of Space Marines in the manner of [Starship Troopers](https://infogalactic.com/info/Starship_Troopers). They can use on board rocket belts or packs to manoeuvre in space and land on an airless moon or asteroid. The large barrel of the mass driver can also launch large calibre rounds, missiles or countermeasures as well.

[image]

*"Have Sting" railgun concept. Space Shuttle included for scale. Illustration by [Scott Lowther](http://up-ship.com)*

And since the spacecraft is both powered and armoured, and capable of using its weaponry to suppress enemy defences and manoeuvring to bring the Space Marines to the proper place, this is probably the most reasonable place to use this system.

Answer (score 1):

In high school physics, you learn that v=at and d=½at². (velocity, acceleration, time, distance respectively) so let's assume a= 20g is the maximum tolerable acceleration for a man, and that a reasonable muzzle velocity is 1000 m/s. This gives you 8.7 sec. of 20g acceleration. Calculating d, we find that a distance of 5.6 kilometers would be required to APPLY that acceleration. The amount of energy required would be enormous, since the 20g assumes the guy is laying perpendicular to the direction of motion, hence the 'shell' he is encased in would be 2+ meters in diameter. In other words, this isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

There are transportation uses for a railgun, two of which are outlined [here](http://gizmodo.com/5987321/ge-is-turning-a-six-flags-roller-coaster-into-an-f-35-launcher). I suppose you could theoretically use a railgun to shoot a train down to the next station, or instead of an F-35 you could launch a glider to some nearby destination. But those both sound expensive and impractical to me.

Answer (score 0):

The physics have been pretty well covered and **the answer is yes**, with a pod of some sort including a catch or parachute mechanism and slow enough acceleration and deceleration this could technically be done.

Now the question becomes in what scenario would this be worthwhile...and believe it or not, one exists. (well at least one)  First, you have to ditch the one mile range, at one mile you are way to close to your enemy for it to not be destroyed...standard artillery can shoot farther than that.  So if you put this on the range of 10+ miles you may have something useful.

In conventional warfare this would be a suicide mission without any likelihood of it also being helpful to the cause.

Now, if you have **this scenario** it could be useful.

- You lack air superiority
- Your ground to air defenses have kept the enemy air craft at bay
- You need to insert special ops troops into the enemy's territory
- You are already actively at war

Stay with me here...

---

So you create a pod that is **both transport** for a human (or maybe two) **AND a guided missile**...or more like a mortar I suppose.

You launch your spec ops guys toward their destination over enemy lines, along with a full artillery bombardment to mask that you are launching people.

At some point along the travel arc the pod ejects your troops and they descend via parachute

The pod continues on and blows something up (well itself AND something else).  This way the pod will hopefully not be identifiable so the enemy won't know you have snuck people behind enemy lines.

Your ops guys go do what ever it is they need to do and are aided by the fact that the enemy is distracted by some sort of explosion that can either have been a diversion or an attempt to soften the target they are after.

Comment: You're going to secretly move a [160m railgun (much shorter and the launch will kill the occupant)](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/59043/760) to within 1 mile of enemy lines without air superiority and set it up in full view of the enemy? If they can do that, might as well just walk in.

Comment: @Schwern I wasn't really limiting my scenario to a 1 mile range on the rail gun...a 1 mile range makes no sense for something so complex (yes I realize the range mentioned in the question is 1 mile.  I was simply trying to provide a scenario in which the power of a railgun could actually be useful.

Comment: Though I should have mentioned that in my answer, I will edit.

Comment: I think you'll have to first demonstrate firing a human-sized projectile, and their gear, 10+ miles from a railgun is feasible. It would have to be ungodly long. And survive while setting it up within easy artillery range.